# Angular 2 CLI and yfiles for HTML 2.0.0 - Cannot read property 'GraphComponent' of undefined

Tags: angularjs, yfiles

#### THE PROBLEM

I am trying to integrate yfiles for HTML into an Angular 2 application that uses the Angular CLI. I am using the latest version of Angular 2 and the latest BETA release of the CLI.

I have installed the types using `npm install --save @types/yfiles`.

I have placed the required yfiles folders in my project and have updated angular-cli.json to include the required sytles and scripts:

```
"styles": [
      "../lib/yfiles.css"
  ],
  "scripts": [
      "../lib/license.js",
      "../lib/yfiles/view-component.js",
      "../lib/yfiles/view-layout-bridge.js",
      "../lib/yfiles/layout-hierarchic.js",
      "../lib/yfiles/layout-tree.js",
      "../lib/yfiles/router-polyline.js",
      "../lib/yfiles/router-other.js"
  ],
```

I have confirmed that a build includes these scripts in the bundled scripts output after running `ng build`.

When trying to reference yfiles the autocomplete works in the IDE (latest Webstorm):

```
graphComponent: yfiles.view.GraphComponent;

constructor(private element: ElementRef,
            injector: Injector,
            resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) { }

ngAfterViewInit() {
    let containerDiv:HTMLDivElement =     
this.element.nativeElement.getElementsByClassName('graph-control-container')  
[0];
    this.graphComponent = new yfiles.view.GraphComponent(containerDiv);

}
```

The project compiles and runs when `ng serve` is issued BUT when I navigate to a route that activates the component that is trying to use yfiles, an error is thrown and reported in the console:

> ```
> error_handler.js:54 EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in ./BrowseVisualisationsComponent class BrowseVisualisationsComponent - inline template:0:0 caused by: Cannot read property 'GraphComponent' of undefined
> ```

I have tried importing the yfiles modules - for example:

```
import 'yfile/view-component'
```

This just prevents `ng serve` from building the application:

```
ERROR in ./src/app/shared/table-relationship-visualisation/table-relationship-visualisation.component.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'yfiles/view-component' in '/home/VMdev/Documents/iotahoe_client/src/app/shared/table-relationship-visualisation'
 @ ./src/app/shared/table-relationship-visualisation/table-relationship-visualisation.component.ts 12:0-31
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi main
```

Any assistance appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scripts provided in the `app.scripts` array will just be loaded as if they would have been referenced with regular `<script>` tags - no module resolving will take place at all.

However, the yFiles modules you provided in the scripts array are "meta modules" that would load the actual implementation files using AMD/CommonJS-style define/require statements. 
Therefore, in order to load the yFiles functionality with angular-cli, you will have to provide the actual implementation files directly:

```
"scripts": [
  "./assets/yfiles/license.js",
  "./assets/yfiles/lib/yfiles/impl/lang.js",
  "./assets/yfiles/lib/yfiles/impl/graph-core.js",
  "./assets/yfiles/lib/yfiles/impl/core-lib.js",
  "./assets/yfiles/lib/yfiles/impl/graph-styles-core.js",
  "./assets/yfiles/lib/yfiles/impl/graph-styles-default.js",
  "./assets/yfiles/lib/yfiles/impl/algorithms.js",
  "./assets/yfiles/lib/yfiles/impl/graph-styles-template.js",
  "./assets/yfiles/lib/yfiles/impl/graph-styles-other.js",
  "./assets/yfiles/lib/yfiles/impl/graph-binding.js",
  "./assets/yfiles/lib/yfiles/impl/layout-core.js",
  "./assets/yfiles/lib/yfiles/impl/graph-layout-bridge.js",
  "./assets/yfiles/lib/yfiles/impl/layout-polyline.js",
  "./assets/yfiles/lib/yfiles/impl/layout-router.js",
  "./assets/yfiles/lib/yfiles/impl/layout-tree.js",
  "./assets/yfiles/lib/yfiles/impl/layout-hierarchic.js"
],
```

It's unfortunate that the modules can't be resolved automatically with this approach even though the yFiles modules adhere to the UMD pattern, but I don't see a better option to make this work with angular-cli right now.

To generate the list of the yFiles implementation modules in the correct order, you can use our yeoman generator with the "script-tags" option: 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-yfiles-app

Comment: Note that with yFiles for HTML 2.1 this is all much easier to setup now. It works great with angular-cli and the new native ES6 modules. There is a demo specifically for angular-cli in the package, now.